# Oracle SQL Update Select

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Going over a mock test for my upcoming test, and I have been stuck on the update select part.

Firstly here is my code so far:

```
    CREATE TABLE UNIT
(unit_id            char(3)     Primary key,
 unit_name          VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 valid_till         DATE        Check(valid_till > '01-Apr-2016'),
 salary             NUMBER(7,2),
 constraint unit_n_unq unique (unit_name));


CREATE TABLE STAFF
(staff_id           NUMBER(3)   Primary key,
 unit_id            Char(3)     References unit(unit_id),
 unit_name          VARCHAR(30) references unit(unit_name),
 name               VarChar(25) NOT NULL,
 dob                DATE,
 gender             Char(1)     Check(gender IN ('M', 'F', 'X')),
 period             NUMBER(2)   Check(period  <= '52'),
 pay                NUMBER(6,2),
 totalpay           NUMBER(10,2));

CREATE SEQUENCE staff_id_seq
    START WITH 100
    INCREMENT BY 1;


CREATE TRIGGER staff_id_trg
    BEFORE INSERT ON STAFF
    REFERENCING NEW AS NEW
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        SELECT staff_id_seq.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.staff_id FROM DUAL;
    END;
    /




INSERT INTO UNIT (unit_id, unit_name, valid_till, salary)
VALUES ('abc', 'dis1', '01-Jan-2017', '56.34');
INSERT INTO UNIT (unit_id, unit_name, valid_till, salary)
VALUES ('def', 'dis2', '02-Jan-2017', '56.34');
INSERT INTO UNIT (unit_id, unit_name, valid_till, salary)
VALUES ('str', 'dis3', '03-Jan-2017', '56.34');



INSERT INTO STAFF (staff_id, unit_id, name, dob, gender, period, unit_name)
    SELECT 123, unit.unit_id,'steve', '01-Jan-2016', 'M', 52, unit.unit_name
    FROM UNIT
    WHERE unit.unit_name = 'dis1';
INSERT INTO STAFF (staff_id, unit_id, name, dob, gender, period, unit_name)
    SELECT 123, unit.unit_id,'bob', '01-Jan-2016', 'M', 52, unit.unit_name
    FROM UNIT
    WHERE unit.unit_name = 'dis2';
INSERT INTO STAFF (staff_id, unit_id, name, dob, gender, period, unit_name)
    SELECT 123, unit.unit_id,'ethan', '01-Jan-2016', 'M', 52, unit.unit_name
    FROM UNIT
    WHERE unit.unit_name = 'dis3';
INSERT INTO STAFF (staff_id, unit_id, name, dob, gender, period, unit_name)
    SELECT 123, unit.unit_id,'rock', '01-Jan-2016', 'M', 52, unit.unit_name
    FROM UNIT
    WHERE unit.unit_name = 'dis1';
INSERT INTO STAFF (staff_id, unit_id, name, dob, gender, period, unit_name)
    SELECT 123, unit.unit_id,'boulder', '01-Jan-2016', 'M', 52, unit.unit_name
    FROM UNIT
    WHERE unit.unit_name = 'dis2';


 UPDATE staff 
    set (staff.pay) = (
    select unit.salary
    FROM unit
    WHERE unit.salary = unit.salary
);
```

What i'm trying to do is right at the bottom.
I am wanting to update the row "Pay" in the table "staff" by using Update Select. This new pay column needs to be Pay = unit.salary / 52.

Looking for some assistance with this.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a correlated subquery for this. Something like this:

```
update staff
set staff.pay = (
        select salary / 52
        from unit
        where unit.unit_id = staff.unit_id
        );
```